# How to generate box equal to sibling attribute value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I need to generate green rectangular boxes putting value from HTML. Value will be any from 1 to 16.
Generated boxes will be equal to value number.

```
<div id="box" value="2"> </div>    <!-- 2 green  box -->
<div id="box" value="5"> </div>    <!-- 5 green  box -->
<div id="box" value="14"> </div>   <!-- 14 green  box -->
<div id="box" value="10"> </div>   <!-- 10 green  box -->
```

How generate boxes with jquery and css??

Comment: The question reads like a "TODO" instead of a question. It would help if you add what you've tried, share the jQuery and CSS you have already, and be specific about where you got stuck.

Comment: Value generated randomly?

Comment: @Mohammad Not randomly

Comment: Show html result you want

Comment: it will be simple green boxes.  Nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `id` attribute should be unique. Use `class` attribute instead. Second, `value` attribute isn't valid for div. Use `data-value` attribute instead.

You need to loop through div has value and create new div after it equal to it value. The [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) insert html after selector.

```js
$(".box").each(function(){
  var value = parseInt($(this).data("value"));
  for (var i = 0; i < value; i++)
    $(this).after("<div class='green'></div>");
});
```

```css
.green{
  height: 10px;
  background: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" data-value="2">2</div>
<div class="box" data-value="5">5</div>
<div class="box" data-value="14">14</div>
<div class="box" data-value="10">10</div>
```

Comment: please help if colors possible this way??     if value 1 = RED box ,      
 value 2 or 3 = Yellow boxes ,        if value any from 4 to 16 = Green boxes '

Answer (score -1):

Numbers of boxes to generate = custom field value

if value 1 = RED box

if value 2 or 3 = Yellow boxes

if value any from 4 to 16 = Green boxes

HTML:

```
<div id="box"> 
     <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'box', true );?> 
</div>
```

Comment: I realize that you are just trying to help but answering the question in PHP is  not very helpful since the question was tagged with `jquery`. What if the OP does not have access to the server side code?

Comment: I am not the user who asked the question. You can see the tags that were used directly underneath the question body.

Comment: @Mahbub_CSE_BD please share i need